# CSS custom shape button with multiple colors

Tags: html, css

I am stuck trying to create this button with CSS. So long I have tried to create predesigned images but they just don't fit together when loaded in a HTML page.

[image: Every square is supposed to be a transparent button]

Every square is supposed to be a transparent button. (The center button has text too but is white.)

[image: That's the page]

That's the page.

Can anybody provide some advice or guidance?

Here is some code for people who requestet it:

```
<div class="caja">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="promociones" ng-click="botonPromo()">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img class="alerta" ng-click="botonAlerta()">
    </div>
  </div>

  <img class="buzon" ng-click="botonBuzon()">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="aprobados" ng-click="botonAprob()">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img class="atm" ng-click="botonATM()">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS (Is impossible to fit the perfectly):

```
.buzonMenu-page .promociones{
  content: url(../img/menu/Artboard-172[4].png);
  width: 100%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .alerta{
  content: url(../img/menu/Artboard-173[4].png);
  width: 100%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .buzon{
  content: url(../img/menu/Artboard-176[4].png);
  width: 100%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .aprobados{
  content: url(../img/menu/Artboard-175[4].png);
  width: 100%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .atm{
  content: url(../img/menu/Artboard-174[4].png);
  width: 100%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .row{
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.buzonMenu-page .col{
  padding: 0%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .col .promociones, .aprobados{
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 9%;
  padding-bottom: 0%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .col .alerta, .buzonMenu-page .col .atm{
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 9%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .row .aprobados, .buzonMenu-page .row .atm{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -31%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .row .aprobados{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -32%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .row .atm{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -1%;
}

.buzonMenu-page .buzon{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: -17%;
  margin-left: -2%;
  width: 39%; 
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem is that it is impossible to fit the images perfectly, as shown on this picture, they always miss by a few pixels:

[image]

So my original question is how to make this 5 buttons with CSS? Something like they did with this question: [CSS custom shape button with two colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951767/css-custom-shape-button-with-two-colors)

Comment: Can you provide code examples?

Comment: How far is each button extended? what is the bounding box? And what should be seen in the middle?

Comment: @Amit Sure, is for Ionic framework so it has some Ionic structures. Let me edit the question.

Comment: @Amit the buttons are square, I'll put the design page.

Comment: And your problem is? (Is it that the edges of the 4 "corner" images/buttons show below the transparent middle button?)

Comment: @Amit see my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is put all your graphics in 1 image (either as a whole, with the background, or just the button borders and transparent areas). Then have this image displayed in the required position in html (either as an element background, or an `img`). You then overlay this image with positioned `div`s representing the buttons. Those "button `div`s" should be transparent. Set event handlers on the buttons and you're done. I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d21a4vad/1/) that shows what it looks and behaves like with a simple colored background, but that can be replaced with anything you need. In the fiddle you can toggle button area visibility (so that you can see that each button is clipped at the correct area).

Comment: Awesome, now is only a matter of playing with the size and absolute position of the squares, on top of the full image.